# How to print out a statement only once in loop

Tags: python, loops

I've got a problem: I've got a sequence of numbers  and a number n. I need to write a programm that  should output all positions of n in the numerical sequence. In case if n is not in the sequence, print the line "not found".
Actually, I have an issue with this "not found". It's needed to be printed out only onece, but it prints out several times. How can I fix it?

```
line = input()
n = input()
line = line.split()
pos_list = []
x = 0
for j in range(len(line)):
        pos_list.append(j)
#print(pos_list)
for i in line:
    if i == n:
        print(line.index(n, x))
    else:
        print("not found")
    x = x + 1
```

For example for line = 3 5 3 6 4, n = 7 I've got:

```
not found
not found
not found
not found
not found
```

If I use `break` after `print("not found")` it always prints not found even `n` is in the sequence

Comment: The logic is incorrect: it's not possible to decide whether `n` is in `line` after checking _any one element_ of `line`. You can conclude that `n` is not in `line` only after checking _all_ elements of `line`.

Comment: The 'else' is tied to the 'if', so your program definition reads "for every number in the list: if the current number is n print the position, if not print not found". You will have to handle your "not found" if you reach the end and still haven't found your number.

Comment: What is it exactly that you want please explain it here in the comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to "remember" if n was found. If not print "not found" once after the loop is done:

```py
line = input()
n = input()
line = line.split()
pos_list = []
x = 0
found = False
for j in range(len(line)):
        pos_list.append(j)
#print(pos_list)
for i in line:
    if i == n:
        print(line.index(n, x))
        found = True
    x = x + 1
if not found:
    print("not found")
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can put this code it works fine:**

```
line = input()
n = input()
line = line.split()
pos_list = []
x = 0
for j in range(len(line)):
        pos_list.append(j)
#print(pos_list)

flag =0
for i in line:
    if i == n:
        flag=1
        print(line.index(n, x))
    x = x + 1

if (flag==0):
    print("not found")
```

but if you want to find substrings, then you this code doesn't works. You are saperating line string into array of strings by dividing line through spaces:
Example:

```
line="hello worldhello helloYou"
n="hello"
```

so here *hello* is at location 0 not on 11, 17 position. Because you are not considering **substring**